# ionic GeoLocation retrieve place an address?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, geolocation

How to retrieve place an address from Lat and Long, from this code:

```ts
doLocate() {

    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
      // resp.coords.latitude
      // resp.coords.longitude
      this.datas = 'Lat: ' + resp.coords.latitude + '' + ' Lon: ' + resp.coords.longitude
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
      });

  }
```

Comment: I've got this : Error getting location PositionError Only secure origins are allowed

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the latitude and longitude to another plugin in order to get the address of the location, see [Ionic Native Geocoder](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-geocoder/) for reference.
OR you can use [Google's Reverse Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)

```
 import { NativeGeocoder, 
    NativeGeocoderReverseResult,
    NativeGeocoderForwardResult, 
    NativeGeocoderOptions } from '@ionic-native/native-geocoder';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

constructor(private nativeGeocoder: NativeGeocoder,private geolocation: Geolocation) { }


let options: NativeGeocoderOptions = {
    useLocale: true,
    maxResults: 5
};

doLocate() {
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
        this.datas = 'Lat: ' + resp.coords.latitude + '' + ' Lon: ' + resp.coords.longitude
        // then pass it to native geo coder plugin after you installed
this.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.latitude, options)
  .then((result: NativeGeocoderReverseResult[]) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result[0]))
    }).catch((error: any) => console.log(error));


    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });
}
```

Comment: I've tried it, but it doesnt work....could you please give me an example how to pass it in this or another code ? Thanks

Comment: @klejz0r code added for reference, try and let me know!

Comment: I've got this : Error getting location PositionError Only secure origins are allowed – klejz0r

Comment: where did you get this error, by running the apk in android  or by running the app in browser using ionic serve?

Comment: on phone...on browser i've got cordova_not_available.

Comment: No. Please give me your skype if u have. Thanks